# How to find duplicates from a Pandas dataframe based upon the values in other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I have a Pandas Df-

```
A= 
[period store  item
1        32     'A'
1        34     'A'
1        32     'B'
1        34     'B'
2        42     'X'
2        44     'X'
2        42     'Y'
2        44     'Y']
```

I need to implement something like this:
If an item has the same set of stores as any other item for that particular period then those items are duplicate.
So in this case A and B are duplicates as they have the same stores for the respective periods.

I have tried converting this into a nested dictionary using this:

```
dicta = {p: g.groupby('items')['store'].apply(tuple).to_dict()
         for p, g in mkt.groupby('period')}
```

Which is returning me a dictionary like this:

```
dicta = {1: {'A': (32, 34),'B': (32, 34)}, 2: {'X': (42, 44),'Y': (42, 44)}}
```

... 
So in the end I want  a dictionary like this.

{1:(A,B),2:(X,Y)}
Although, I am not able to find any logic how to find the duplicate items.
Is there any other method that can be done to find those duplicate items

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use [`.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html). Make sure to pass `['period', 'store']` as `subset` and `keep` as `False` so all the rows will be returned.

```
 print(A[A.duplicated(subset=['period', 'store'], keep=False)])
```

Outputs

```
  period store item
0      1    32    A
1      1    34    A
2      1    32    B
3      1    34    B
4      2    42    X
5      2    44    X
6      2    42    Y
7      2    44    Y
```

Note that according to the logic you specified all the rows are duplicates.

**EDIT** After OP elaborated on the expected format, I suggest

```
duplicates = A[A.duplicated(subset=['period', 'store'], keep=False)]
output = {g: tuple(df['item'].unique()) for g, df in duplicates.groupby('period')}
```

Then `output` is `{1: ('A', 'B'), 2: ('X', 'Y')}`.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the quick help, But what i really need is something like this... 1=(A,B) ,2=(A,B) , where 1 and 2 are periods and A,B are the duplicate items for that periods and having the same set of Stores. I know I am asking a lot but this is really urgent and considering my limited knowledge in this I have to seek help.

Comment: @thebigshaikh then how it is different than what you already got as `dicta` in the question?

Comment: That dictionary isn't giving me the items corresponding to the period ID which are duplicates

Comment: @thebigshaikh Yes, it does. The outer keys are `1` and `2`

Comment: The dictionary is just giving me this, dicta = {1: {'A': (32, 34),'B': (32, 34)}, 2: {'X': (42, 44),'Y': (42, 44)}} , whereas I need something like this {1:(A,B),2:(X,Y)} , here 1 and 2 are periods and A, B,X,Y are the items for which the set of stores is exactly the same.  The dictionary is just the represenation of the original dataframe in a different formar

Comment: Sorry for bothering. Your edit works only if all the rows are duplicates, if there are few rows which are not duplicates then it doesn't give the right op. {1:(A,B),2:(X,Y)}, in this final dictionary I want only those items who's stores are exactly the same. So in this case A,B and X,Y have the same stores for periods 1 and 2 respectively. Thanks for everything up till now but unfortunately my problem isn't solved.